# ESP32 Stack canary watchpoint triggered. Why?

Tags: esp32, arduino-esp32

I have a program that can encrypt and decrypt a text with Boneh-Franklin encryption. This works great on a PC, but for some reason causes a constant reboot on ESP32 with the following error message:

```
setup2
setup2.2
setup2.3
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception)
Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (loopTask) 
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x40083774  PS      : 0x00060b36  A0      : 0x3ffb0120  A1      : 0x3ffb0060  
A2      : 0x68efa751  A3      : 0x3ffb0938  A4      : 0x3ffb0720  A5      : 0xfb879c5c  
A6      : 0x61b36b71  A7      : 0x0006970f  A8      : 0x01709af4  A9      : 0x01709af4  
A10     : 0xfaa5dfed  A11     : 0x01a3ff3b  A12     : 0x76651dec  A13     : 0x00000001  
A14     : 0x00000000  A15     : 0x04adbe74  SAR     : 0x0000001e  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000001  
EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x400f1cc5  LEND    : 0x400f1cc9  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000  

ELF file SHA256: 0000000000000000
```

I use an Arduino ESP32 environment, CONFIG_ARDUINO_LOOP_STACK_SIZE is set to 8192 in main.cpp, 8k stack should be enough to run it. It works perfectly on PC, it’s a mystery to me why not on ESP32. Can anyone help? I absolutely ran out of ideas.
For the Boneh-Franklin implementation I used this library: https://github.com/miracl/core
My own code is ~200 lines, I have uploaded it to Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EY0mGC2UiVNhE68b5Q0VB9JIY2Owbpxg/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code, it isn't unreasonable that the stack will require more than 8192 bytes as a lot of big objects are allocated on the stack, both in your code and in the library, e.g.:

**loop()**

- `csprng RNG` – 128 bytes
- `ECP2 pPublic` – 264 bytes
- `ECP2 cipherPointU` – 264 bytes
- `ECP privateKey` – 132 bytes

**encrypt(...)**

- `ECP pointQId` – 132 bytes
- `char[] dst` – 256 bytes
- `BIG l` – 40 bytes
- `FP12 theta` – 532 bytes

**PAIR_fexp()**

- `FP2 X` – 88 bytes
- `BIG x` – 40 bytes
- `FP a, b` – 2 * 44 = 88 bytes
- `FP12 t0, y0, y1, y2, y3` – 5 * 532 = 2660 bytes

Increase your stack size. It will likely help.

Comment: Thank you. I have increased the stack size to 64k. ESP32 still keeps rebooting but the error message is different now:
setup2
setup2.2
setup2.3
setup2.4
kkkk
encrypt
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (StoreProhibited). Exception was unhandled.
Core 1 register dump:
PC      : 0x400d964b  PS      : 0x00060930  A0      : 0x800d1048  A1      : 0x3ffcfe40  
A2      : 0x3ffd04a4  A3      : 0x0000000b  A4      : 0x3ffb855c  A5      : 0x3ffb858c  
Etc.

Comment: Use a backtrace analyzer (such as https://github.com/tve/esp32-backtrace) to decode where exactly the code crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I got to this page by googling my own troubles so thought I would add my solution here

I experienced this error recently and by using a series of `Serial.println`'s was able to trace to an infinite loop created in the code